# How can I use formContext instead of Xrm.Page in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, client, dynamics-crm

`Xrm.Page` is deprecated and as per the requirement, I need to use `formContext` instead. I'm having difficulties trying in making my function work when I use anything except `Xrm.Page`

```
export function OpenQuickCreateForm(formId: string = '9add862d-3ceb-4342-99cf-fe5a952eebf8', context: Xrm.FormContext): void {

const emailadd = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("emailaddress1");

const firstName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("firstname");

const lastName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lastname");
```

I want to use `formContext.getAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the latest @types/xrm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/xrm

Comment: Yup I already installed it

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Just use execution context parameter for your handlers and extract form context out of it like: 
`function handler(context) {
 const formContext = context.getFormContext();
 
 const emailadd = formContext.getAttribute("emailaddress1");
 const firstName = formContext.getAttribute("firstname");
 const lastName = formContext.getAttribute("lastname");
}`

Comment: Forgot that one of my requirement was to use primaryControl as a parameter, it's working now

     function OpenQuickCreateForm(primaryControl, formId = '9add862d-3ceb-4342-99cf-fe5a952eebf8') {
         var formContext = primaryControl;
         const emailAdd = formContext.getAttribute("emailaddress1");